# Unable to get the value of Index in string literal operator, is there any way to get the value, apart from the way I have tried?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Below is my javascript code, I am unable to get the value in string literal

```
 $("#<%= JobMatrixGrid.ClientID%>").find("tr").each(function (index) {
            $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                $(this).find("input[id*=OpeningsInputText]").blur(function () {
                    alert("Hello" + index);
                    var jobMatrixOpenning = '<%=JobMatrix[index].NumberOfOpenings %>';
                    alert("This is " + jobMatrixOpenning);
                });
            });
        });
```

Also tried `'<%=JobMatrix['+index+'].NumberOfOpenings %>';`

But this too did not help, `JobMatrix` is list of List in code behind, backend

The *index* value is not considered in that place, but *index* value is seen in alert.

Comment: because the asp.net part is written long before the JS is executed. and on different computers. so you can inject values from c# into js but not the other way around.
Write all `NumberOfOpenings` into an JS Array and let the code access that array by index.